# PHP7 with APCu - Call to undefined function apc_fetch()

Tags: php

I have installed APCu extension in PHP7

But I get this error

```
Call to undefined function apc_fetch()
```

[image]

Answer (score 27):

Starting with PHP 7.0, APCu removed the option for full backwards compatibility with APC that existed with APCu in PHP 5.5 and 5.6.

You will need to add the APCu Backwards Compatiblity Module on top of apcu to make it work. (https://pecl.php.net/package/apcu_bc)

```
pecl install apcu_bc
```

Answer (score 18):

You need to install apcu and apcu backward compatibility for PHP7

On Ubuntu 14.xx you first need to install php7.0 by using the repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-apcu
sudo apt-get install php7.0-apcu-bc
```

Then restart apache

For ubuntu 16.xx. You can already install apcu

```
sudo apt-get install php-apcu
```

Then add the repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main"
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install php-apcu-bc
```

Comment: These packages seem to not exists in ubuntu 16 repos

Comment: You are right I will update the answer with the info for the package :)

Comment: I know I'm late to the party but it's worth noting that you'll also need to restart apache after the Ubuntu 16 instructions as well.

Answer (score 6):

Such an installation doesnt work for me - ubuntu doesnt have apcu-bc package.

```
apt-get install php7.0-apcu-bc
```

My installation

```
sudo apt-get install php-dev
sudo pecl install apcu_bc-beta
```

After that I changed /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/apcu-ini to

```
extension=apcu.so
extension=apc.so
```

Note, that apc.so must be AFTER apcu

Comment: Is the `-beta` part required for the install from pecl?

Comment: @Sonny sorry, I dont know

Answer (score 2):

APC and APCu are different modules.

You have APCu installed, however, you are using APC functions.

Try apcu_fetch or install apc, if that is possible for PHP7.

Answer (score 1):

In Centos using IUS repo, install `apcu` and `apcu-bc` packages for php7:

```
sudo yum install php71u-pecl-apcu php71u-pecl-apcu-bc
```