# apc doesn't work in php 7

Tags: php, apc

I get error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apc_clear_cache()

Could you please tell me how to fix this issue?
I have this version of php

> PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )

although phpinfo displays:

```
apcu

    APCu Support    Enabled
    Version 5.1.3
    APCu Debugging  Disabled
    MMAP Support    Enabled
    MMAP File Mask  no value
    Serialization Support   php
    Build Date  Apr 5 2016 02:16:47
    Directive   Local Value Master Value
    apc.coredump_unmap  Off Off
    apc.enable_cli  Off Off
    apc.enabled On  On
    apc.entries_hint    4096    4096
    apc.gc_ttl  3600    3600
    apc.mmap_file_mask  no value    no value
    apc.preload_path    no value    no value
    apc.serializer  php php
    apc.shm_segments    1   1
    apc.shm_size    32M 32M
    apc.slam_defense    On  On
    apc.smart   0   0
    apc.ttl 0   0
    apc.use_request_time    On  On
    apc.writable    /tmp    /tmp
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36129259/php7-with-apcu-call-to-undefined-function-apc-fetch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP7 with APCu - Call to undefined function apc\_fetch()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36129259/php7-with-apcu-call-to-undefined-function-apc-fetch)

Comment: format error and information blocks.

Answer (score 2):

I use php7.0 and package maintainers provide php7.0-apcu-bc - backward compatibility package translating apc_* calls to apcu_*.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I solved issue, installing from other rep, like this one.

```
apt-get remove php-apcu
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update
apt-get install php-apcu
```

Answer (score 1):

When PHP 7 was first released, APC cache was not compatible.  Now there is a package for it.

```
apt-get install php7.0 php-apcu
```

Answer (score 0):

APCu differs from APC in the sense that it's APC stripped of opcode caching. It's only key-value data store part.

You have APCu module enabled so you can call `apcu_*` functions accordingly:

```
apcu_clear_cache();
```