# apc_store installed but does not return correct value

Tags: php, variables, caching, memory, php-7.3

I am trying to use apc_store to store a token variable that would continously change, thus need to be created by one php script, and accessed by another php script.

---

Environment:
PHP: version 7.3
OS: Ubuntu 18.04

References followed:

[Stackoverflow: Troubleshooting apc_store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36129259/php7-with-apcu-call-to-undefined-function-apc-fetch)

[PHP Manual - apc_store](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php)

---

**Installation procedure:**

```
sudo apt-get install php-apcu
sudo apt-get install php-apcu-bc
```

**Installation result:**

```
php-apcu is already the newest version (5.1.18+4.0.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
php-apcu-bc is already the newest version (1.0.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+20191129).
```

**The problem**

Even though I do not get an error message, the system
will not return expected result, e.g. the string "abc", 
further on the result indicates "bool(false)" which should be "bool(true)".

**Question:**

How can I get the result to show?:

```
string(3) "abc"
```

**Other tests**
I tried to change  /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/apcu-ini to

```
extension=apcu.so
extension=apc.so
```

...giving the error:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

**My php script:**

```
<?php
$token = "abc";
apc_store('token_1', $token);
var_dump(apc_fetch('token_1'));
```

**Result:**

bool(false)

**Expected result:**

string(3) "abc"

---

**Troubleshooting:**

**Checking apc:**

Result:

```
$ php -i | grep apc

/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/25-apcu_bc.ini
apc
apcu
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.enable_cli => Off => Off
apc.enabled => On => On
apc.entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.mmap_file_mask => no value => no value
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.serializer => php => php
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 32M => 32M
apc.slam_defense => Off => Off
apc.smart => 0 => 0
apc.ttl => 0 => 0
apc.use_request_time => On => On
```

Comment: are you running it from CLI? 
Can you try if it works through http request?

Comment: @matiit I am following the instructions from above mentioned "PHP apc_store" which creates a php file and I trigger the php file from a terminal.

Comment: Can you show the result of `php -i | grep apc`?
I am guessing you have:  apc.enable_cli => Off => Off

Comment: @matiit I updated the question. At the end you find the result of [php -i | grep apc].

Comment: @matiit. Works now. When I breakout the [var_dump(apc_fetch('token_1))] to another file, I do get boo(false) but that is a separate concern. I will register another question for that. Will go ahead and approve below answer.

Comment: @mattit Would be great if you could check. Highly appreciated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054235/cannot-use-apc-fetch-to-fetch-a-stored-variable-from-the-cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable apc for cli.

Find out which php.ini file is loaded:

`php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"`

Edit above file and add:

`apc.enable_cli=On`

And try again.

Edit after question has been updated:

Just add above line to the following file:
`/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini`