# Cannot use apc_fetch to fetch a stored variable from the cache

Tags: php, caching, apc, php-7.3

Environment: PHP: version 7.3 OS: Ubuntu 18.04

References followed:

[PHP - apc_store](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php)

[PHP - apc_fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-fetch.php)

---

I cannot use apc_fetch from separate PHP script "file2" to access stored cache.

It does work when trigger apc_fetch from file1.

---

**File: 1_store_variable_in_memory.php**

```
<?php

$token = "my_token_value";
apc_store('token_1', $token);
// var_dump(apc_fetch('token_1')); // Moved to file 2
```

**File: 2_access_memory_stored_variable.php**

```
<?php

var_dump(apc_fetch('token_1'));
```

Result from file 2:

```
bool(false)
```

Expected result from file 2:

```
string(14) "my_token_value"
```

Comment: You can't use APC like that. 
The stored data is not shared between processes like that. You might wanna use something else like redis or memcached

Comment: @matiit Understood, please move your comment into an answer and I will approve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

APC in PHP cli gets cleared after process is ended, moreover the memory is not shared between multiple php cli processes; because of it this is probably not the tool you want to use to solve your problem.

Try Redis or memcached if you need a cache that is persisted between processes.