# Call to undefined function apcu_add()

Tags: php, xampp, lumen, apc, apcu

I'm currently working on an api which has been developed using `Lumen 5.4`. I'm trying to run this on my local `XAMPP for Linux 7.4.3`. But I keep getting the following error,

```
lumen.ERROR:
    Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError:
    Call to undefined function xxx\Prometheus\Storage\apcu_add() in
    /opt/lampp/htdocs/xxx-api/vendor/xxx/php-prometheus-exporter/src/Storage/APCU.php:78
```

---

Current PHP version is `7.4.3`. I have installed `apcu` along with `apcu_bc` and added the following to `php.ini` as well,

```
extension=apc.so
apc.enabled="1"
```

but I'm not seeing any `apc` related info in `phpinfo.php` page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP7 with APCu - Call to undefined function apc\_fetch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36129259/php7-with-apcu-call-to-undefined-function-apc-fetch)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Thanks for you suggestion. But unfortunately it does not answer my question. As I have mentioned, I already installed `apcu` and `apcu_bc` but it does not work.